# overloading '+' operator to work on inbuilt datatypes like int, etc and not classes

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, operators

I was just getting my hands dirty with overloading operators and all and wanted to overload the '+' or '-' operator and kind of interchange their definitions not for user defined classes but built in datatypes like int, long long, etc. For example... cout<<2+3; outputs -1.
Is it possible??

Comment: Just about all books, classes and other texts about operator overloading should contain the disclaimer: *Do not change the semantics of the operators*. Not even for your own classes.

Comment: Well that's the word, "dirty". In practice it is usually better (more readable/maintainable) to define your own functions with proper names then to overload operators. The one exception are wrapper classes and things not included as standard types that have "common operators" like addition/multiplications on their types (e.g. matrices)